# Send data array or object from ajax jquery post to php method

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, laravel

There is my JQuery function that get all form fields value and push them in array:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#details_form').submit(function(e) {
        e.getPreventDefault();
        var result = $(this).serializeObject();
        $.post($(this).prop('action'), {
                'data': result
            },
            function(data) {
                alert(data.msg);
            },
            'json'
        );
        return false;
    });

});
```

it works really good (it send all of data):

```
{"_token":"w35HLqCZi61ki9QOlu6MFwWxYNbBoiEJkcQ58G2b","id":"contact_1","name":"t","surname":"fg","address":"iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii","contact[]":["16151515","2325556"]}
```

but loading the page that i target $(this).prop('action') instead send back json response immediatelly via alert.

But, if i remove `e.getPreventDefault();` the JQuery script returns **error 500** with this response: `{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given","file":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\rubrica\\app\\controllers\\ContactController.php","line":145}}` like if PHP can't get nothing......

This is my PHP function in ContactController of **Laravel Framework**:

```
    public function contact_process() {
        $contact_id = trim(Input::get('id'));
        $contact_name = trim(Input::get('name'));
        $contact_surname = trim(Input::get('surname'));
        $contact_address = trim(Input::get('address'));
        $telephones = array_filter(Input::get('contact'));
if ($contact_id !== '' &&  $contact_name !== '' && $contact_surname !== '' && $contact_address !== '' && $telephones !== '') {

        if ($contact_id == 'new') {

            $new_contact = new Contact;
            $new_contact->name = $contact_name;
            $new_contact->surname = $contact_surname;
            $new_contact->address = $contact_address;
            $new_contact->save();
            $LastInsertId = $new_contact->id;

            foreach ($telephones as $value) {
                $new_detail = new Detail;
                $new_detail->telephone = $value;
                $new_detail->contact_id = $LastInsertId;
                $new_detail->save();
            }

            $response = array(
                'status' => 'success',
                'msg' => 'Nuovo contatto aggiunto'
            );

            return Response::json($response);

        } else {

            list($tmp, $id_temp) = explode("_", $contact_id);

            $get_contact = Contact::find($id_temp)->first();

            if ($get_contact) {

                $get_contact->name = $contact_name;
                $get_contact->surname = $contact_surname;
                $get_contact->address = $contact_address;
                $get_contact->save();

                $delete_details = Detail::where('contact_id', '=', $id_temp)->delete();

                foreach ($telephones as $value) {
                    $new_detail = new Detail;
                    $new_detail->telephone = $value;
                    $new_detail->contact_id = $id_temp;
                    $new_detail->save();
                }

                $response = array(
                        'status' => 'success',
                        'msg' => 'Contatto aggiornato'
                );

                return Response::json($response);

            }
        }
}
        $response = array(
                'status' => 'error',
                'msg' => 'Compila tutti i campi ed inserisci almeno un numero di telefono'
        );

        return Response::json($response);

    }
```

This is my form (Telephone inputs are dinamic):

```
    <form method="POST" action="http://localhost/rubrica/public/contact_process" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-bootstrap" id="details_form" autocomplete="off">
<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="HeC6RwznFYuemIvP68pHYuET634fgQoZQCtL7ed3">
<input id="contact_id" name="id" type="hidden" value="contact_1">
<div class="bg_contact">
    <div class="image_contact">
        <label for="immagine" id="" class="">Add Image</label>
        <input name="image" type="file" id="immagine"> </div>
    <div class="rif_contact">
        <div class="name_contact">
            <input placeholder="Name" id="name" name="name" type="text" value="John"> </div>
        <div class="surname_contact">
            <input placeholder="Surname" id="surname" name="surname" type="text" value="Wayne"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="address">
    <div class="label_address">
        <label for="address">Address</label>
    </div>
    <input placeholder="Address" id="address" name="address" type="text" value="2nd street"> </div>
<div class="bg_details">
    <label for="contacts">Contacts</label>
    <div class="content_detail">
        <input type="text" name="contact" class="contact_details" placeholder="Telephone" value="656346843" id="detail_161">
        <button onclick="delete_detail_exist(this,161)" id="remScnt" type="button">Remove</button>
    </div>
    <div class="content_detail">
        <input type="text" name="contact" class="contact_details" placeholder="Telephone" value="56196856" id="detail_160">
        <button onclick="delete_detail_exist(this,160)" id="remScnt" type="button">Rimuovi</button>
    </div>
    <div class="content_detail">
        <input placeholder="Telephone" class="contact_details" id="p_scnt" name="contact" type="text">
        <button id="addScnt" onclick="add_detail_field(this)" type="button">Add</button>
    </div>
</div>
<input id="save" type="submit" value="Save"> </form>
```

Comment: It seems that Input::get('contact')) returns null,so this might do the tricks: Input::get('contact[]')) ( I'm not sure, I can't test it)

Comment: done but nothing is changed :(

Comment: This happen when i commented `e.getPreventDefault();`. If instead i leave `e.getPreventDefault();` it works but with changing page to the target "contact_process" instead of stay in the same page and receive an alert with msg

Comment: with `$session_data = unserialize(Input::get());` i get this error: `unserialize() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`. With `$session_data = unserialize(Input::get('data'));` get this other error: `The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.`

Comment: When you use $('#something').submit(), it will submit the form, so the page will be reloaded (or going to the next page). So I guess you should try to use <input id="save" type="buttun" value="Save">, and bind the onclick event: $('#save').on('click',function(){ //Do your stuff here, get your vars and pass them to the ajax call })